# good job vs good work, work vs job

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you please take a look at these sentences? (I have no additional context, only the sentences)
Is it possible to use here either of the words --- work/job?

- *Being a fireman is a dangerous _______.*

Fireman is a job, but **being** is an action...so could it be "work" here meaning activity?

- *I have a long list _____ to do before I go away on holidays.*

Jobs or work? A long list of tasks or a long list of activities?

- *Cleaning out the garage was a big _______.*

Can it be a big task? Can it be a great work which we put a lot of effort into?

Examples from the internet:

> Okay, I have made a list of jobs for everyone.
>
> The Government had established *a list of work* that children were
>   prohibited to perform, including farm work, and criminal liability for
>   using child labour had been tightened.
>
> To add to the information provided in the comments on part 1, article
>   11, of the Convention, it should be noted that *a list of work* that
>   women are prohibited to do has been drafted, taking into account
>   unhealthy and dangerous environmental factors.
>
> The forum, after had done *a big work* to create its branches all over
>   the country, organised on 23-24 of June 1995 the First National
>   Conference.
>
> We got our weapons, but this was *a big job*, and we didn't want to go
>   off half-cocked.
>
> It was *a big job* to learn it.

---

When we say "good job" does it mean only that the task is completed?

When we say "good work" does it mean that the *workship* was good?

---

Thanks~

Comment: [Good Work ≠ Good Job](http://languagelore.net/2011/04/good-work-%E2%89%A0-good-job/) interesting point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Job" is countable, "work" is not, so you would use an article with "job" but not with "work".  Also, you wouldn't normally use "big" with work--a big job vs. a lot of work.

Your fireman example: "a dangerous job", or "dangerous work".

Second example: "a" refers to the list so you could use either one: "of jobs" or "of work".

Garage example: "a big job" or "a lot of work".

"Good job" vs. "good work": the difference is just a nuance.  "Good job" would generally refer more to the successful outcome of the task, although it could also refer to the quality of the effort.  "Good work" would refer more to the quality of the work that went into it, but would normally be said (at least without qualifications), about a successful endeavor.  If someone was doing a task for the first time and did high quality work to achieve just an acceptable but unimpressive result, someone would probably tell them "good work" rather than "good job".